# Environment variables not registering in Prisma schema

Tags: javascript, node.js, prisma

I am finding the only way the Prisma schema can detect environment variables is to include a `.env` file in the root directory of its app.

I am using docker compose to build a few services, one of which is an app that manages a database using Prisma. The environmental variables is available in the app via `process.env` however Prisma can not detect this using the `env` function.

Here is how I am accessing the variable in `schema.prisma`:

```
datasource db {
  provider = "postgresql"
  url      = env("DATABASE_URL")
}
```

And I am passing the variable in the docker compose in this way:

```
  app:
    build:
      context: ./app
    environment:
      DATABASE_URL: ${DATABASE_URL}
```

How can I make this function detect environment variables that don't necessarily belong to a `.env` variable?

Comment: Are you sure `DATABASE_URL: ${DATABASE_URL}` is getting set? Try `docker exec containerId env`

Comment: Yes I can see it there (along with others such as `PATH`, `NODE_VERSION` etc).

Comment: I can also access the variable via `process.env["DATABASE_URL"]`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I eventually worked this out! When I am running commands in my terminal I am running them outside of the docker container. So the prisma code running inside docker works perfect, but the commands I run outside can't see that .env file.

I was able to solve by adding the env values to my scripts. It may not be the most elegant solution but it works. For example:

```
eval $(grep '^DATABASE_URL' ../.env) prisma db pull && prisma generate
```